# Sumar números en Jquery

Tags: jquery

Como podría sumar esos números, los cuales son los precios de varios productos pero llegan todos en una sola variable. Así tengo la función que trae todo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
var idproducto = [1,3,5];
      
      idproducto.forEach(function(elemento) {
        
        vtexjs.catalog.getProductWithVariations(elemento).done(function(product){
          //console.log(product);
          var name = product.name;
          var price = product.skus[0].bestPriceFormated;
          var img = product.skus[0].image;          
          
          html = "<div class='items'><div class='imgproduct'><img src=" + img + " alt=''></div><div class='details'><p>" + name + "</p><p class='priceformat'>" + price + "</p></div></div>";
          $(".products").append(html);
          
        });         

      })
      
      $('.products .priceformat').text();
```

Comment: Lo único que ocupas es sumar esos precios

Comment: y son números enteros, sin decimales?

Comment: pues están con decimales, pero mi duda es como sumar 3 precios en una sola variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primero hay que eliminar todos los puntos, usando [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/replace) con una expresión regular, buscando `\.`, con el modificador `g` para que sea global y, después, separar por '$' con [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/split). Finalmente, se usa [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce) para recorrer y sumar todos los valores.

```js
let precios = "$1.690.000$9.999.876$9.999.876";
// Eliminar puntos y separar por $
let numeros = precios.replace(/\./g, '').split('$');
// Recorrer para sumar
let suma = numeros.reduce((a, b) => {
    // Sumar número actual
    a += parseInt(b) || 0;
    return a;
}, 0);
// Comprobar
console.log(suma);
```